# Server 2008 R2 blu-ray driver problem?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, vhd

I'm attempting to make my win 7 laptop dual boot to a vhd where I will install server 2008 r2.  Creating the vhd, booting to it, with a bootable usb drive w/ the server 2008 r2 sp1 iso, no problem.  During the install it complains about not having a driver for the cd-rom, which on my laptop is a blu-ray.  In Windows 7 the driver is the standard cdrom.sys.  But I cannot seem to find a driver for this that will allow the install of server 2008 r2 to proceed?  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally gave up trying to find a better cdrom.sys, and just removed the drive.  Install went fine, and once I had the os up and running, put the blu-ray drive back in and it even recognized it fine.  Very odd.